Deletion of specific byte ranges in large JSON files with mmap library in-place
I'm attempting to delete a specific range of bytes using the mmap library from large JSON files. The size of these files can vary from a few hundred megabytes to several gigabytes (4.08 GB).
However, the issue arises with larger datasets, as memory becomes filled and it becomes impractical to flush it regularly.
I'm able to find the offsets of the range of deleted bytes in the file and retrieve the content that was deleted. I created method, where I try to flush changes regularly:
def delete_bytes(self, mmapped_file, start, end, chunk_size=4089):
    # Calculate the size of the content after the range to be deleted
    remaining_size = len(mmapped_file) - end
    chunk_size = min(chunk_size, remaining_size)

    offset = end
    original_start = start
    
    flush_frequency = 100

    while remaining_size > 0:
        # Determine the size of the current chunk to process
        current_chunk_size = min(chunk_size, remaining_size)

        # Read data from the file at the current offset
        mmapped_file.seek(offset)
        data = mmapped_file.read(current_chunk_size)

        # Write the read data to the new offset
        mmapped_file.seek(start)
        mmapped_file.write(data)

        print(f"Original offset: {start} New offset: {start} Remaining size: {remaining_size}")

        # Flush the changes periodically to ensure data consistency
        if (start - original_start) % (current_chunk_size * flush_frequency) == 0:
            print("Flushing")
            mmapped_file.flush()

        # Update pointers and counters for the next iteration
        start += current_chunk_size
        offset += current_chunk_size
        remaining_size -= current_chunk_size

However, if I keep the chunk size small, it takes an eternity to complete the operation. On the other hand, if I increase the chunk size, it fills up the memory again.
The documentation of the mmap library states that the method can be called with parameters offset and size: flush([offset[, size]])
After implementing this method, I found that it's not supported with two parameters and it only takes the start offset. After adding it, I always receive the error: offset out of range
Moreover, I tried to flush the file at the end of the loop with some delay instead. I implemented deleting bytes from the file using the move method instead of seek and write or deleting the variable data after writing. In all scenarios, the results were the same and I was unable to free up memory.
Is there any other approach or tool that would delete a specific range of bytes in-place without creating additional files or copies?
Thank you in advance.

Is there any other approach or tool that would delete a specific range of bytes in-place without creating additional files or copies? First, don't use mmap.  Playing extraneous games with virtual memory is not a magic wand that makes everything faster, and in this case those extraneous games either make everything S-L-O-W or unworkable.  Just read the data from end of the file, write it where it needs to be, then truncate the file to the new length.

At first sight, JSON is not a proper format to be manipulated in "byte ranges". If for no other reason, due to free white space and variable length character encoding used in utf-8 - not to mention order-free key/value mappings.

Think about what you're doing.  If you have a 1MB file and you delete bytes 100 through 199, the remaining 999,800 bytes must be rewritten.  Disks have no concept of "deleting in the middle".  In short, JSON is a poor choice for what you're doing.  You should be using a real database, like MySQL or Postgres.

instead of diving into your code, or your question as is, I'd suggest creating new JSON files instead, and copy only the fields/data of interest to them, using libs to read  JSON files partially if needed be (check https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/ )

I understand your concerns, however this code is part of a JSON/Hex editor that I'm trying to implement. The user has full control over which range of bytes should be deleted or inserted. Regarding the remaining bytes mentioned by @TimRoberts, I am aware of them and that's why I attempted to use flushing by chunks or method which I mentioned in my question, but the result was the same. The only option I see is to use streams, as jsbueno also mentioned.

One more bit of advice.  A hex editor is a terrible way to deal with JSON.  It's structured data, and should be dealt with as a structure.
